# Another WSDL importer for Delphi?

Tags: web-services, delphi, wsdl

Delphi(6-7-2005-2007-2009)  Wsdl Importer is badly :(
i'm looking another wsdl importer for delphi. (like Web Service Toolkit For Lazarus)
anybody know ?

Answer (score 6):

Did you get the version from [here](http://cc.codegear.com/Item/24535), I had some problems with D7, I got the link from Babet.

Answer (score 1):

The [Free Pascal Web Service Toolkit](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Web_Service_Toolkit) seems to support Delphi as well:

> "Web Service Toolkit” is a web services package for FPC, Lazarus and
>   Delphi; “Web Service Toolkit” is meant to ease web services
>   consumption and creation by FPC, Lazarus and Delphi users.

It includes a WSDL importer wizard and a command-line importer:

[image: WSDL importer]
http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/images/2/24/Wst_lazarus_importer.PNG

And a graphical type library editor:

http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/images/0/0a/Wst_type_lib_edtr.PNG